# Differences between "Dark Current", "Sleep Current" and "Quiescent Current" in automotive related products

Tags: current-measurement, remote-control, sleep

I am from automotive electronics tier 1 manufacturing company which makes Automobile locks and Remote keys.

In our remote keys, our team uses the term **"Dark Current"** for the default current consumed by a device when it is powered up and not being used. This is used to calculate the battery life of the product and is usually <0.1 uA.

Q1) How is this term different from **"Quiescent Current"** or **"Sleep Current"**?

We have an EOL (end of life) testing machine which use a mechatronic based setup and precise DMM to check all parameters of the Remote key PCBA.

We get about 1-2% rejection (NG) for Dark Current limit (>0.1 uA) but 95% of these NG parts are OK on repeated testing during analysis and work fine but our QA department insists on these **being OK on first test run only**.

Q2) What can be the **probable reasons of these NG parts becoming OK** on repeated testing?

- Do we account for **False calls** by our EOL setup?

Comment: If you measure it twice and get different readings ... my immediate question is how is the testing machine calibrated?  If they are > 0.1uA ... how much more are they?  How long are they over the limit?  "Do we account for false calls by our EOL setup" ... not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: - The DMM is a 6 months old machine and has been tested against standard resistive loads to validate the readings.
- 1st reading : Can go from 0.2uA to 19 mA in worst case
- 2nd and subsequent readings : All within acceptance range


- False calls by EOL setup means WRONG call by the machine (similar to AOI machine wrong call during SMT process). Product is correct but the machine gives false call.

Comment: Dark Current is normally used for optoelectronic devices such as optocouplers and fibre optic receivers to show how much they leak in the absence of any light.

Comment: What you call Dark Current is commonly referred to as Sleep Current.  Generally, a microcontroller is put in a low-power sleep mode where it does nothing until awoken by signal such as a button press.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that QA, not engineering, decides what constitutes a properly functioning product.  Lastly, I think you need take a close look at your testing equipment and process to determine the reason why properly functioning product is not passing on the first test.  If it were me, the first place I would look is how the product is connected to the DMM.  There very well may be a way to incorrectly connect it such that the DMM gives an erroneous reading.